# Spark Streaming - HBase Bulk Load

Tags: hadoop, hbase, pyspark

I'm currently using Python to bulk load CSV data into an HBase table, and I'm currently having trouble with writing the appropriate HFiles using `saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile`

My code currently looks as follows:

```
def csv_to_key_value(row):
    cols = row.split(",")
    result = ((cols[0], [cols[0], "f1", "c1", cols[1]]),
              (cols[0], [cols[0], "f2", "c2", cols[2]]),
              (cols[0], [cols[0], "f3", "c3", cols[3]]))
    return result

def bulk_load(rdd):
    conf = {#Ommitted to simplify}

    keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringToImmutableBytesWritableConverter"
    valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter"

    load_rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda line: line.split("\n"))\
                  .flatMap(csv_to_key_value)
    if not load_rdd.isEmpty():
        load_rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///tmp/hfiles" + startTime,
                                        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2",
                                        conf=conf,
                                        keyConverter=keyConv,
                                        valueConverter=valueConv)
    else:
        print("Nothing to process")
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

`java.io.IOException: Added a key not lexically larger than previous. Current cell = 10/f1:c1/1453891407213/Minimum/vlen=1/seqid=0, lastCell =  /f1:c1/1453891407212/Minimum/vlen=1/seqid=0 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.AbstractHFileWriter.checkKey(AbstractHFileWriter.java:204)`

Since the error indicates that the key is the problem, I grabbed the elements from my RDD and they are as follows (formatted for readability)

```
[(u'1', [u'1', 'f1', 'c1', u'A']),
 (u'1', [u'1', 'f2', 'c2', u'1A']),
 (u'1', [u'1', 'f3', 'c3', u'10']),
 (u'2', [u'2', 'f1', 'c1', u'B']),
 (u'2', [u'2', 'f2', 'c2', u'2B']),
 (u'2', [u'2', 'f3', 'c3', u'9']),
```

. . .

```
 (u'9', [u'9', 'f1', 'c1', u'I']),
 (u'9', [u'9', 'f2', 'c2', u'3C']),
 (u'9', [u'9', 'f3', 'c3', u'2']),
 (u'10', [u'10', 'f1', 'c1', u'J']),
 (u'10', [u'10', 'f2', 'c2', u'1A']),
 (u'10', [u'10', 'f3', 'c3', u'1'])]
```

This is a perfect match for my CSV, in the correct order. As far as I understand, in HBase a key is defined by {row, family, timestamp}. Row and family are combination are unique and monotonically increasing for all entries in my data, and I have no control of the timestamp (which is the only problem I can imagine)

Can anybody advise me on how to avoid/prevent such problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this was just a silly error on my part, and I feel a bit foolish. Lexicographically, the order should be 1, 10, 2, 3... 8, 9. Easiest way to guarantee correct ordering before loading is:

```
rdd.sortByKey(true);
```

I hope I can save at least one person the headaches I had.